# Operator is negative-definite on a space of functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

**Prove that the operator
$$D \equiv \Big[ \frac{d^2}{dx^2} - m^2\Big], m \in \mathbb{R}$$
is negative-definite on the space of functions
$$H=L^2[0,2\pi], (f,g)\equiv \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(x)} g(x) dx.$$
Conclude that $Ker(D)$ contains only the zero vector $f(x) =0$**

I know we have to prove that $(f, Df)<0$ where $()$ is a scalar product

Scalar Product is: $(f,g)\equiv \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(x)} g(x) dx.$

$(f,Df)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(x)} Df(x) dx.$

Any idea/help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Assume for the moment that you have enough regularity to integrate the second derivative term by parts once, and that the values at the endpoints are zero (so that there is no boundary term in the integration by parts). Then use a density argument to extend the inequality that you get to all of $L^2$. This density argument amounts to showing that the scalar product is $L^2$-continuous and that the closure of $C^1_c$ in $L^2$ is $L^2$, where $C^1_c$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions with compact support inside $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I am not sure how you got here: $\int_0^{2\pi} f f^{"}$, what happened to $\overline{f(x)}$ 
 
 $(f,Df)= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_0^{2\pi} \overline{f(x)} (f" -m^2f) dx.$
 
 How do i get from here to what you said?

Comment: I restricted attention to the term with the $f''$; the other term already does what you want. The conjugate doesn't hurt anything, you still want to integrate by parts, moving a derivative from the $f''$ to the $f$. You should find that $\int_0^{2 \pi} \overline{f} f'' dx = -\int_0^{2 \pi} \overline{f'} f' dx = -\int_0^{2 \pi} |f'|^2 dx$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $\partial=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dx}$ is a densely-defined selfadjoint on the domain consisting of periodic, absolutely continuous functions $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ for which $f'\in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$. This unbounded operator has a basis of eigenfunctions $e_{n}=e^{inx}$ with $\partial e_n = ne_n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The square of a selfadjoint operator such as $\partial$ is also densely-defined, positive and selfadjoint on $\mathcal{D}(\partial^{2})$ consisting of all $f \in \mathcal{D}(\partial)$ for which $Df \in \mathcal{D}(\partial)$. In this case $\mathcal{D}(\partial^{2})$ consists of all twice absolutely continuous functions $f$ on $[0,2\pi]$ for which $f$ and $f'$ are periodic and $f''\in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$. Such an operator $\partial^{2}$ is always positive because $f \in \mathcal{D}(\partial^{2})$ implies $(\partial^{2}f,f)=(\partial f,\partial f)=\|\partial f\|^{2}$.

You may also work directly with $\partial$ in terms of twice absolutely continuous functions $f$ for which $f$, $f'$ are periodic, and $f \in L^{2}$. Using integration by parts,
\begin{align}
     (\partial^{2}f,f) & = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f''\overline{f}dx \\
   & =\left.-\frac{1}{2\pi}f'\overline{f}\right|_{0}^{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f'\overline{f'}dx \\
   & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f'|^{2}dx = \|\partial f\|^{2}.
\end{align}
The evaluation terms disappear because $f$ and $f'$ are periodic and absolutely continuous.

Your operator $D$ is $-\partial^{2}-m^{2}$. So
$$
         (Df,f) = -\|\partial f\|^{2}-m^{2}\|f\|^{2}.
$$
Therefore, if $Df=0$ for some $f\in\mathcal{D}(D)$, then $(Df,f)=0$ which implies that $f=0$.

Comment: @Lucas : You're welcome.